# Change the URL of a renamed GitLab Pages repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I have a Gitlab Pages project site hosted as `my.gitlab.io/old`.

I rename the project repo to `new`. When I push again, it still publishes to `my.gitlab.io/old`.

How do I change it to `my.gitlab.io/new`?

Answer (score 6):

To rename a repository:

1. Navigate to your project’s **Settings > General > Advanced** settings.
2. Under **Change path** section, change the `Path` to your liking.
3. Hit <kbd>Change path</kbd> button for these changes to take effect.

[image]

Comment: I did this but the old path still works for cloning, push, pull, etc. Shouldn't the old path stop working?

Comment: The redirects are available as long as the original path is not claimed by another group, user, or project.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/index.html#what-happens-when-a-repository-path-changes

Answer (score 0):

In GitLab, a Project name and its path are different.

I assume the Project has the following configuration:

- **Project name:** `new`
- **Path:** `gitlab.com/my/old`

It should be:

- **Project name:** `new`
- **Path:** `gitlab.com/my/new`